# Share session data across multiple tabs

Tags: reactjs, session

I have a simple login with Remember me checkbox. When a user clicks remember me I store user data and token in *localStorage*, when the user does not check the Remember me I store user data and token in *sessionStorage*. I have configured to share session data across multiple tabs also. But when I open the 4th tab or 5th tab I run into an infinite loop in *eventListner*

Here is my logic.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', event => util.sessionStorageTransfer(event, sessionData, setSessionData, sessionLogout), false);
```

util.js

```
sessionStorageTransfer(event, sessionData, setSessionData, sessionLogout) {
    if (!event.newValue) {
        return;
    }
    if (event.key === 'REQUESTING_SHARED_CREDENTIALS') {
        window.localStorage.setItem('SHARING_AUTH', JSON.stringify(sessionData));
        window.localStorage.removeItem('SHARING_AUTH');
    }
    if (event.key === 'SHARING_AUTH') {
        console.log(event.key);
        if (event.newValue) {
            setSessionData(JSON.parse(event.newValue));
        }
    }
    if (event.key === 'REQUESTING_LOGOUT') {
        sessionLogout();
    }
}
```

I have console log the point that infinite loop occurs. How can I solve this issue?